# Cannot access or print Ajax response in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting a response from my ajax call but how can I access or at least print the response?

Here's my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '../backorderReport.php',
         data: { from : from, to : to  },
         dataType: "JSON",
         success: function(data){
                    console.log(data[0].orderID); //not printing anything
                    console.log(data);            //not printing anything
         }
 });
```

Here is my php file

```
$from = $_POST["from"];
$to = $_POST["to"];
$orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_orderrecords WHERE orderDate BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'");

foreach($orders as $order){
            $orderID = $order->orderID;
            $orderDate = $order->orderDate;
            $status = $order->status;
            $clientID = $order->clientID;
            $bill = $order->bill;
            $ship = $order->ship;
            $pay = $order->pay;
            $total = $order->total;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_clients WHERE clientID = '".$clientID."%'");     

           foreach($results as $order){
                  $clientsName = $order->clientsName;
           } 

           $c = str_replace(' ', "&nbsp;", $clientsName);

           $orderItem = array(
                    'orderID' => $orderID,
                    'orderDate' => $orderDate,
                    'orderStatus' => $status,
                    'clientsName' => $c,
                    'bill' => $bill,
                    'ship' => $ship,
                    'pay' => $pay,
                    'total' => $total
                 );

           echo json_encode($orderItem);
}
```

And I'm getting this response

```
{"orderID":"26","orderDate":"2016-05-11","orderStatus":"Active","clientsName":"Pebbe\u00a0Kristel\u00a0A
\u00a0Bunoan","bill":"Billed","ship":"Delivered","pay":"Unpaid","total":"1200.00"}{"orderID":"27","orderDate"
:"2016-05-13","orderStatus":"Completed","clientsName":"Lovely\u00a0Carbon","bill":"Billed","ship":"Delivered"
,"pay":"Paid","total":"4650.00"}
```

How can I print the response and place the data in a table? Thank you for your help!

Comment: use var resultArray = $.parseJSON(data);

Comment: If `console.log(data)` doesn't return you anything, then you are probably not getting a response from the server.

Comment: @DainisAbols, how come when I call the ajax, the console shows the response, json, along with the header, post, html and cookies. What should I do? I edited my question above to show how I'm doing my json_encode.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, I edited my question to show how I'm doing my json_encode. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are echoing one valid json string, for each record that matched the query. Hence getting something like :

```
{ record_1 } { record_2 }
```

which is invalid json. You want an array like :

```
[{ record_1 },{ record_2 }]
```

Modify slightly your php as follows :

```
 $from = $_POST["from"];
 $to = $_POST["to"];
 $orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_orderrecords WHERE orderDate BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'");

$records = [];      // adds an array for the records

foreach($orders as $order){
        $orderID = $order->orderID;
        $orderDate = $order->orderDate;
        $status = $order->status;
        $clientID = $order->clientID;
        $bill = $order->bill;
        $ship = $order->ship;
        $pay = $order->pay;
        $total = $order->total;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_clients WHERE clientID = '".$clientID."%'");     

       foreach($results as $order){
              $clientsName = $order->clientsName;
       } 

       $c = str_replace(' ', "&nbsp;", $clientsName);

       $orderItem = array(
                'orderID' => $orderID,
                'orderDate' => $orderDate,
                'orderStatus' => $status,
                'clientsName' => $c,
                'bill' => $bill,
                'ship' => $ship,
                'pay' => $pay,
                'total' => $total
             );
       $records[] = $orderItem;  // push each order item on the array
 }
 echo json_encode($records);    // echo the array
```

ps : test for boundary conditions before the echo, eg. no records found matching the query, and other oddities that could lurk in your server-side software.

Comment: Glad this helped. Dont let the php bugs bite you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse

```
success: function(data){ 
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
     }
```

Comment: Not loop, he needs to access `orderID` like `parsedData.orderID` or `parsedData['orderID']`

Comment: Hi! I'm still not getting anything in the console.

Comment: Specifying the `dataType = 'json'` the `data` object argument for the `success` function will automatically be parsed into from string to object form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse json string

```
success: function(data){
    var resultArray = $.parseJSON(json);
    console.log(resultArray[0].orderID); 
    console.log(resultArray);            
}
```

Comment: @user3383911 if this answer is helpful to you them please accept it

Comment: I'm still not getting anything in the console.